# Inserting into database through Dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dataset

I am trying to add information from the DataSet to the database; I checked in Google and it seems that this is the way it should do it but when I compile I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'The object reference is not defined to an instance of an object.
>   dt was null

My code:

```
public void AjouterPatient()
{
    dt = ds.Tables["ListePatient"];          

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["CodePatient"] = code;
    row["NomPatient"] = nom;
    row["AdressePatient"] = AdressePatient;
    row["DateNaissance"] = DateNaissance;
    row["SexePatient"] = Sexe;

    ds.Tables["ListePatient"].Rows.Add(row);

    UtilitiareBD.Connecter();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.Update(ds, "Patient");

    UtilitiareBD.Deconnecter();

    MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");
}
```

Comment: Seems that dt is a variable that you have not declared as a DataTable yet?

Comment: You need to show the code that initializes `ds`.

Comment: ds is a DataSet

Comment: Hasn't your table changed from "ListePatient" to "Patient"?

Comment: The Problem is caused from   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

Answer (score 0):

Where does 'dt' come from? If it isn't being instantiated somewhere you need to create an instance of the object before using it.

`var dt = new DataTable();`

Give that a try and see if it gets you past the Null Reference.

Optionally you can add the name of the table to the initialization as follows.
`var dt = new DataTable("ListePatient");`

Comment: I tried that but the DataTable Still giving me a Null Reference

Comment: Do you still have the `dt = ds.Tables["ListePatient"];` line in there? If so if `ds.Tables["ListePatient"];` is null then you are nulling out dt. Try commenting that line out and running it. You can add a name to the table in the DataTable by adding that to the Declaration `var dt = new DataTable("ListePatient");`

Comment: J.R. Bye Thank you for your answer but its still the same problem .The point is that  my dataset is not null, it has a datatable " ListePatient" but when i try to add a new row to the datatable it throws an exception

Comment: Yea but when you reference that data set it is nulling out the data table. If you comment that out for a debug you can see if you can at least create the data row. If you can do that then you can figure out how to use that data row.